# how to keep session enabled in firebase/auth js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

When I log in or register everything works perfectly. But if I reload the page I have to log in again. Is there any way around this? I have tried setting up persistence myself but it doesn't work.
This is my code

```
const iniciarSesion = (e) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
    .then(() => {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                setVentana("Tienda")
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    })
}
const registar = (e) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            setVentana("Tienda")
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most browser-based environments Firebase already persists and restores the user credentials upon reloading the page. From the Firebase documentation on [auth persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence):

> For a web application, the default behavior is to persist a user's session even after the user closes the browser. This is convenient as the user is not required to continuously sign-in every time the web page is visited on the same device.

So if your code runs in a browser, you shouldn't need to call `setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)`. What you **do** need however, it so detect in your code when Firebase has restored the signed in user.

Restoring the user upon reloading the page requires that Firebase call to the server, to amongst others check if the account has been disabled. While this call is being made, the `currentUser` will be `null`. To get notified when the user has been restored, and for other changes in authentication state, you'll want to use an auth state listener as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

In this code you'll then call `setVentana("Tienda")` to navigate to the correct window.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it was very helpful. I just need to figure out how to find out the state of useState that I had before reloading the page to know which window to navigate to.

Comment: Yes, and that is precisely what an auth state listener can help with. Did you try implementing it, and calling `setVentana("Tienda")` in there?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) so if reload page , redux store will persist.
this document my help you
https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/integrations/redux-persist.html

Answer (score 0):

Implement redux w/ toolkit (easiest way to set up redux IMO) - you can follow [this tutorial](https://dev.to/dawx/react-authentication-with-firebase-3ma4)

Important tip is to update the state with the `onAuthStateChanged` method available in the firebase package, instead of changing it directly during the sign-in/ sign-up function